# How I can authentication with WSO2 Carbon Framework

Tags: wso2

I write very simple program and deploy to Application Server
I use this code to obtain tenant context:
ie. index.jsp

```
<%
    CarbonContext cCtx = CarbonContext.getCurrentContext();
    int tenantId = cCtx.getTenantId();
    String tenantDomain = cCtx.getTenantDomain();
    String tenantUsername = cCtx.getUsername();
%>

<b>User Information</b>
    <br> Tenant ID:
    <%=tenantId%><br> Tenant domain:
    <%=tenantDomain%><br> Tenant user name:
    <%=tenantUsername%><br>
```

After I login, using BASIC authentication, index.jsp show result:
User Information
Tenant ID: -1234
Tenant domain: carbon.super
Tenant user name: null

Could you help me? thanks.

Comment: I don't know what this is about, but I don't think it has anything to do with Carbon as the tag is defined.

Comment: You have got the CarbonContext correctly, but seems like the issue with the authentication. If you got authenticated successfully, the carbon context get updated with username and you should be able to get username as you getting it now. Can you please update the question how do you doing the authentication?

Comment: I use authentication with BASIC, I don't know how to create custom login page with Form authentication. My web.xml file:
<login-config>
  <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  <realm-name>Example Form-Based Authentication Area</realm-name>
  <!-- <form-login-config> <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page> 
   <form-error-page>/error.jsp</form-error-page> </form-login-config> -->
 </login-config>

Comment: And another question, Developer Studio show error: CarbonContext cannot resolved. Could you help me fix this.Thanks

Comment: I believe you are already authenticated successfully. That's why you get the tenant id. You can also access the super tenant's registry instance etc. I *believe* the username is not getting set if you login in this manner. That's why `cCtx.getUsername()` returns null.

Comment: You need to add org.wso2.carbon.utils:4.2.0 as a dependency to your eclipse/maven project. The groupId:artifactId:version can be extracted from here - http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/org/wso2/carbon/org.wso2.carbon.utils/4.2.0/org.wso2.carbon.utils-4.2.0.pom